# In cocoa: why changing image size it also change image resolution?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image-resizing

I am using this code to change size to an image and then create a new file with new dimensions. All is working fine but it changes the image dpi resolution and I don't want that... the initial image dpi res is 328 and after the resizing it becomes 72... how to keep the original dpi resolution?
Here is my code:

```
- (void)scaleIcons:(NSString *)outputPath :(NSURL *)nomeImmagine
 {

 NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[nomeImmagine path]];
if (!image)
    image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[nomeImmagine path]];

NSSize outputSize = NSMakeSize(512.0f,512.0f);
NSImage *anImage  = [self scaleImage:image toSize:outputSize];

NSString *finalPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingString:@"/icon_512x512.png"];
NSData *imageData = [anImage TIFFRepresentation];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
NSData *dataToWrite = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
[dataToWrite writeToFile:finalPath atomically:NO];
}



- (NSImage *)scaleImage:(NSImage *)image toSize:(NSSize)targetSize
{
if ([image isValid])
{
    NSSize imageSize = [image size];
    float width  = imageSize.width;
    float height = imageSize.height;
    float targetWidth  = targetSize.width;
    float targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    float scaleFactor  = 0.0;
    float scaledWidth  = targetWidth;
    float scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    NSPoint thumbnailPoint = NSZeroPoint;

    if (!NSEqualSizes(imageSize, targetSize))
    {
        float widthFactor  = targetWidth / width;
        float heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;
        }

        scaledWidth  = width  * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }

        else if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }

        newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:targetSize];

        [newImage lockFocus];

        NSRect thumbnailRect;
        thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
        thumbnailRect.size.width = scaledWidth;
        thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

        [image drawInRect:thumbnailRect
                 fromRect:NSZeroRect
                operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
                 fraction:1.0];

        [newImage unlockFocus];
    }


 }

return newImage;
}
```

Any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks... Massy

Comment: What are the dimensions of the source image?

Comment: 1024 x 1024 it happens with png file as well with psd file

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048597/how-to-change-image-resolution-in-objective-c

Comment: I already tryed to use that but I don't know how to integrate it into my code... do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've been able to change the res... using the code taken by the post pointed by trojanfoe... I added this to my code before to write the file:

```
NSSize pointsSize = rep.size;
NSSize pixelSize = NSMakeSize(rep.pixelsWide, rep.pixelsHigh);

CGFloat currentDPI = ceilf((72.0f * pixelSize.width)/pointsSize.width);
NSLog(@"current DPI %f", currentDPI);

NSSize updatedPointsSize = pointsSize;

updatedPointsSize.width = ceilf((72.0f * pixelSize.width)/328);
updatedPointsSize.height = ceilf((72.0f * pixelSize.height)/328);

[rep setSize:updatedPointsSize];
```

only problem now is that the final resolution is 321,894 and not 328... but it's already something!